# How to combine numeric and text in an array smartly

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, double, cell

I have a numeric array which i wish to combine with a text array.

```
TX = {'a' 'b' 'c'}
NM = magic(30)
```

combined = ([TX NM])

How can i manage to get the following new structure out of it:

COMBI = a b c are in columns 1,2,3 and have the same value from row 1:30,
first numeric value of NM starts in column 4 and goes until column 33, and has values from row 1:30.

I always get but i want all values in one matrix

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 30x30 double
```

but i want

```
1: 'a'  'b' 'c' 30 columns of double in cell notation, i.e. '3.54' 
2: 'a'  'b' 'c' 30 columns of double in cell notation, i.e. '3.54' 
3: 'a'  'b' 'c' 30 columns of double in cell notation, i.e. '3.54' 
...

30: 'a' 'b' 'c' 30 columns of double in cell notation, i.e. '3.54'
```

How can i do that?

**UPDATE 1** : thanks Daniel, I updated the example code with ' '
**UPDATE 2** : problem solved by constructing an empty array first and pasting numeric or text data inside, thanks Benoit_11
**UPDATE 3** : an extra snipped is added to Benoit's great solution by working with unequally sized numeric matrices:

```
%// To generalize;
n = numel(TX);
NumRowCol = size(NM,1);
NumCol = size(NM,2); % <- the 'new' part considers column size 
%// Initialize the cell
MyCell = cell(NumRowCol,n+NumCol);
%// Insert text in first 3 columns
MyCell(:,1:3) = repmat(TX,NumRowCol,1);
%// Fill the rest with your numeric array in "cell" format.
MyCell(:,n+1:end)= num2cell(NM);
%// Display MyCell
MyCell;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you for a small example provide the expected output in correct matlab syntax?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I updated the example I provided to work in matlab. Is there anything left unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like the following. I use a numeric array of size 5 x 5 to demonstrate but that's the same idea in your case.

```
clear
clc

TX = {'a' 'b' 'c'};
NM = magic(5);

%// To generalize;
n = numel(TX);
NumRowCol = size(NM,1); %/// Since you use a magic matrix there are as many rows and columns. You might need to update this with different numeric arrays.

%// Initialize the cell
MyCell = cell(NumRowCol,n+NumRowCol);

%// Insert text in first 3 columns
MyCell(:,1:3) = repmat(TX,NumRowCol,1);

%// Fill the rest with your numeric array in "cell" format.
MyCell(:,n+1:end)= num2cell(NM);

%// Display MyCell
MyCell


MyCell = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'    [17]    [24]    [ 1]    [ 8]    [15]
    'a'    'b'    'c'    [23]    [ 5]    [ 7]    [14]    [16]
    'a'    'b'    'c'    [ 4]    [ 6]    [13]    [20]    [22]
    'a'    'b'    'c'    [10]    [12]    [19]    [21]    [ 3]
    'a'    'b'    'c'    [11]    [18]    [25]    [ 2]    [ 9]
```

Comment: Awesome then glad to help!

Comment: added a small piece to work with fewer or more columns than rows, thanks anyways, works very well now.